# conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow just stuck in Solving environment

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I am trying to run this statement in MacOS.

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

It just stuck at the

```
Solving Environment:
```

Never finish.

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.5.12
```

Comment: How many packages already exist in the environment? The most likely solution to this is to install tensorflow in a fresh environmnet.

Comment: Even then, I've occasionally known conda to take a l o o o o n g time at the Solving Environment stage. I'd leave it an hour or more before concluding it's really stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On win10 I waited about 5-6 minutes but it depends of the number of installed python packages and your internet connection.
Also you can install it via Anaconda Navigator

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked untill i ran this in conda terminal:

```
conda upgrade conda
```

Note that this was for poppler (conda install -c conda-forge poppler)

Answer (score 3):

One can also resolve the "Solving environment" issue by using the [`mamba`](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) package manager.

I installed tensorflow-gpu==2.6.2 on Linux (*CentOS Stream 8*) using the following commands

```
conda create --name deeplearning python=3.8
conda activate deeplearning
conda install -c conda-forge mamba
mamba install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu
```

To check the successful usage of GPU, simply run either of the commands

- `python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print('\n\n\n====================== \n GPU Devices: ',tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'), '\n======================')"`
- `python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print('\n\n\n====================== \n', tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])), '\n======================' )"`

References

- [Conda Forge blog post](https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2021-11-03-tensorflow-gpu/)
- [`mamba install` instead of `conda install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430429/conda-install-c-conda-forge-prophet-takes-forever-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

The same error happens with me .I've tried to install tensorboard with anaconda prompt but it was stuck on the environment solving .So i've added these paths to my environment variables:

```
C:\Anaconda3 

C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin

C:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin

C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin

C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction by nekomatic.

I left it running for 1 hour.  Yes. it is finally finished.

But now I got the conflicts

Solving environment: failed

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> bleach==3.0.2=py37_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> html5lib==1.0.1=py37_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> numexpr==2.6.8=py37h7413580_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> scikit-learn==0.20.1=py37h27c97d8_0
  - tensorflow
 Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Try creating an environment with an earlier version of Python (preferably 3.5)

Comment: Why does it need > 1 hour to install Tensorflow? :(

Comment: What's the difference between using `conda` and `pip install`?  If I can do it with `pip install` why should I waste half an hour using `conda`?

Comment: I am not using conda now. I am using virtual env and pip install now.