# %conda install -c conda-forge prophet takes forever to install

Tags: python, pip, conda, facebook-prophet, prophet

Trying to install fb prophet but it takes so long, it has been running for both vscode editor for almost an hour

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a new environment:

```bash
conda create -n prophet -c conda-forge prophet
```

or, if insisting on current environment, use [Mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```bash
conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba
mamba install -c conda-forge prophet
```